# Play store shows my app as Unsupported for Nexus 7 and others

Tags: android, android-manifest, apk, android-screen-support

I'm trying to publish an app to Play Store, but when I upload the app, the Nexus 7 and other devices are shown as not compatible. The app should be restricted to tablets, as its interface is not not for phones. I didn't set requirements for hardware not present in Nexus 7 and I support all displays from 600dp up.
I found similar questions, but all related to camera or phone permissions... any ideas?
This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it.mypackage.stuff"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                      android:normalScreens="false"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true"
                      android:anyDensity="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"></uses-feature>

<application> Stuff.... </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Use **`aapt dump badging`** to see if there is anything particularly out of sorts.

Comment: @CommonsWare The result of aapt dump badging seems normal: 
[...]
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-implied-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE','requested WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen','assumed you require a touch screen unless explicitly made optional'
[...]
supports-screens: 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--' 'it'
densities: '160' '240' '320' '480'
native-code: 'armeabi' 'armeabi-v7a' 'mips' 'x86'
[...]

Comment: Then, at least for the moment, I would assume that it is a Play Store hiccup. Give it a day or two and see if the problem goes away on its own.

Comment: I couldn't manage to resolve the problem as now. I'm wondering the problem can be related to the native code included. Aapt shows the APK as compatible with: native-code: 'armeabi' 'armeabi-v7a' 'mips' 'x86'.
What is the nexus 7's CPU architecture?

Comment: It should be `armeabi-v7a`. However, that is backwards-compatible with `armeabi` anyway.

Comment: Thank for your help. Tried removing all the libraries except armeabi, the app is working fine but the market shows the exact compatibility list as before. Is there a way to know the reason a single device is marked as not compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem and solved it. I felt very stupid when I realized the problem was I weren't incrementing the "versionCode" field in the AndroidManifest.xml.
The Android Developer Console shows a strange behaviour: if you upload an apk to an unpublished application without incrementing the versionCode, the apk isn't replaced, and no error is shown. So the apk remains the first one uploaded, and all the changes made in the new apk are lost.